# A question about generators, commutators, and center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying a paper from Archiv der Mathematik and I had a question from parts of it.
Let $G$ be a group such that the set $S=\{[x_i : y_i ] ∶1\le i\le d\}$ of its commutators is finite. Consider the finitely generated subgroup $H=\{x_1,y_1,… ,x_d,y_d\}$ of $G$.
Note that $S$ is also the set of commutators of $H$. Let $H/Z(H)$ be generated by the images of $g_1,g_2,…,g_r \in H$. We may assume that $r\le 2d$, but we do not need it here. Note that $g \in Z(H)$ if and only if $g$ commutes with each of $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_r$.

- My question is why the last sentence is true; of course one case is obvious (I mean when $g\in Z(H)$), but I cannot derive the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ commutes with $g_1,\cdots,g_r$ then it commutes with their inverses and any words formed out of them and their inverses, which is every element of the group because they are generators.

Why? Think about inverses yourself first. Then, observe if $g$ commutes with $a,b,c,\cdots$ then

$$\color{Blue}{g}abc\cdots=a\color{Blue}{g}bc\cdots=ab\color{Blue}{g}c\cdots=abc\color{Blue}{g}\cdots=\quad\cdots\cdots\quad =abc\cdots \color{Blue}{g}$$

Comment: @Aref: Have you noticed that this post is lighting the general case??!

Comment: Surely the post is right, but observe that we considered $g_i s$ as generators of $H/Z(H)$ and want to show if g from H commutes with them it is in Z(H). I don't think this post is proving this; If I am wrong correct me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Aref But that is easy, since the $g_i$ and $Z(H)$ generate all of $H$. If $g$ commutes with the $g_i$s, and it commutes with everything in $Z(H)$ automatically, then by this reasoning it commutes with everything in $H$.

Comment: Yes, thats right. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write $H=\langle x_1,y_1,\dots , x_d,y_d\rangle$ in this context. (angle brackets instead of braces).

Anyway, let $w\in \{x_1,y_1,\dots , x_d,y_d\}$ be arbitrary.  Assume that $g$ commutes with all $g_i$.  It suffices to prove that that $g$ commutes with $w$. But we know that $wZ$ is a word in $g_1Z,\dots,g_rZ$, say  $w(g_1,\dots,g_r)Z$.  Thus $w= w(g_1,\dots,g_r)z$ for some $z\in Z(H)$. As $g$ commutes with all $g_i$ and certainly with $z$, $g$ commutes with $w$.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the angle brackets. I am sure it must be like this, but i dont know why braces was used in the original text. and i cannot understand what you mean by : wZ is a word in w(g1,…,gr) ?

Comment: I'll fix the answer to clarify things.

Comment: Thank. But please check that if this is better to write or not :  $wZ$ is a word in $g_1Z,\dots,g_rZ$, say  $(g_1,\dots,g_r)Z$.  Thus $w= (g_1,\dots,g_r)z$ for some $z\in Z(H)$. As $g$ commutes with all $g_i$ and certainly with $z$, $g$ commutes with $w$.

Comment: Not better, in my opinion.  $w(g_1,\dots,g_r)$ stands for a function of $g_1,\dots, g_r$ (i.e. a sum of products of powers of the generators), where as dropping the "$w$" may be misleading.